# Save an id with the text in a table view cell

Tags: swift

Xcode/Swift

I have a web service sending me names and Ids. I display the name in the table view cell. I'd like to attach the id to the cell for later retrieval. Is there an easier way to do this than the custom cell approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class that stores text and id and instantiate one for each cell or you can store ID in cell.detailTextLabel.text and hide that.